# Standard Output not expected Error

Tags: java

This are other problems I ran into that is having the same issue.  Can anyone point out my logic error in the following below:

Question: A regular polygon is an n-sided polygon in which all sides are of the same length and all angles have the same degree... (Exercise 4.5)

This was my response:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise04_05 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of sides: ");    
        double n = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the side: ");    
        double s = input.nextDouble();    
        double area = n * Math.pow(s, 2) / 4 * Math.tan(Math.PI / n );

        System.out.println("The area of the polygon is " + area);                        
    }
}
```

Please explain where the Logic error is. i commented out the code or else I'll keep getting errors preventing me from submitting the question.

Comment: seems to work OK for a square of length 4 (if you do some rounding)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. *Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: The second `*` should be a `/`.  Think order of operations.

Comment: @ScaryWombat a square is the only polygon it gives the correct answer for though, because `tan( pi / 4 )` is 1, so multiplying instead of dividing makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is wrong and it contains an error.

First `/ 4` is an integer division which is rounded to an `int`, so you get mostly an error. You have to use `/ 4.0` so you get the right division.

The formula for calculation the area of a polygon is

> A = 1 / 4 * n * s<sup>2</sup> * cot(PI / n)

*Note it is cotangens, not tangens.* As java.math has no cotangens you have to calculate it by yourself, e.g. `1 / Math.tan(x)`.

So finally this should work for you:

```
double area = n / 4.0 * Math.pow(s, 2) / Math.tan(Math.PI / n );
```